# Test if object is a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

A JavaScript function receives one argument that may be a DOM element or not. How ensure that argument is a DOM element and not another object?

Answer (score 2):

With modern browsers I think it is something like

```
e instanceof Element
e instanceof Text // text node
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

To check if it is a DOM object.

```
if(arg.tagName){ 
   //Its a dom element
}
```

To check if it is a jQuery object

```
if(arg.jquery){
   //Its a jQuery object
}
```

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PY8MT/)**

Alternatively you can try this function which will return true if the element passed as an argument is a DOM element.

```
function isElement(o){
  return (
    typeof HTMLElement === "object" ? o instanceof HTMLElement :
    typeof o === "object" && o.nodeType === 1 && typeof o.nodeName==="string"
);
```

Comment: This fails if `arg = { tagName: 'pancakes' }`.

Comment: I added another solution in the same answer please take a look.

Comment: `Element` should work, no? There's also text nodes to consider. But yeah, asking exactly the question you're interested in is better than poking around with indirect checks on properties and the like.

Answer (score 1):

`el instanceof Node` will give you `true` if *el* is a part of DOM.
`el instanceof Element` - `true` if it is also an Element.

Answer (score 0):

just check the object that is it have a innerHTML function or not.

For example :

```
function (obj ) {
    if(!!obj.innerHTML) // force the function to be boolean 
    {
         // do something here if it was a html element 
    }
    else {
         // do stuff here if it wasn't
    }



}
```